# How to pass a list of lists from jsp to action class in Struts2

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

I need to pass a list of check boxes from jsp to action class.
I have 3 tables 
1. Questions(qid,description) -- which has a set of questions
2. Options(oid,description)  -- that has a set of options
3. Question_Options_Mapping(qid,oid) -- mapping table between question and options
for each question there will be different set of options that are displayed as check boxes. User can select more than one check box and submit. When ever a user submits a question I need to track which question he answered and what are the options he selected in another mapping table Question_Answered(qid,oid).

I'm able to retrieve questions and corresponding options and displayed to user but I don't have any idea on how to track the questions he answered and the options he selected.
I need the questions in a list and for each question a separate list should be maintained for options and pass it to action class.

The way I'm displaying Questions and corresponding options to user is

```
<table class="layoutMinTable">
    <s:iterator value="Questions">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <s:property value="description"/>
        </td>
        <s:iterator value="Options" status="stat" id="item">
        <td>
        <s:checkbox theme="simple" name="%{#attr.item.description}" value="%{#attr.item.checked}"/>
            <s:property value="%{#attr.item.description}"/>

        </td>
        </s:iterator>

    </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

Comment: Think HTTP request: How would you map this?

Comment: Don't use `id` attribute, it's deprecated.